# How can I integrate MoEngage for web push notifications using different server-side methods?

Tags: push-notification, web-push, moengage

I'm in the process of implementing web push notifications for my website and I'm considering MoEngage as a potential solution. However, I'm seeking guidance on integrating MoEngage for web push notifications using various server-side methods.
What are the available methods to integrate MoEngage for web push notifications without focusing on specific server-side technologies?
Are there general principles or patterns to follow when integrating MoEngage for web push notifications regardless of the server-side technology used?
How do I handle subscriptions and send push notifications using MoEngage across different server-side methods?

I've tried to find resources or documentation from MoEngage, but I couldn't find comprehensive guidance on integrating web push notifications across various server-side methods. I expected to find clear instructions or examples covering different server-side approaches, but I haven't found relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moengage Push APIs: https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404548252820-Push-API#01GKF5C20A072Z3DE8XFTR0ABB.
The sample code given here, uses Python. But you can use any language you want .